# Python multithreading/multiprocessing assert all processes are synced and paused before continuing

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, synchronization

My main application spawns several child processes or threads. This number is variable and the processes/threads can finish at any time. For the most part, the children can run normally. However, at some point I need to be able to suspend all of the children alive at a given moment and ensure they are all at the same point before continuing.

This is exactly what I need to achieve in the main script:

1. Count the number of children still alive.
2. Pause all alive children.
3. Confirm that all alive children are indeed paused where I need them to be (as opposed to stuck in a long calculation).
4. When all children are synced and paused, do some processing and saving.
5. Release all the children to continue.

None of the `threading` synchronisation primitives seem to do everything I need. Some of my ideas:

1. `Event` objects in all the children. This satisfies most of my needs but I cannot check to see if a child is indeed waiting on an `Event`. There does not seem to be an `Event.poll()` method or similar.
2. Use a `Barrier`. This seems to have almost all of the elements I need, however, it is immutable in terms of the number of parties to wait for and the `Barrier` releases for ALL threads not just the main. I have thought of a hacky workaround where the main calls `reset()` when `n_waiting` is the correct number I am waiting for. This causes the waiting children to release the wait with a `BrokenBarrierException` which I can catch. This seems very hacky.
3. I have also considered using a `Semaphore` where the main script calls `acquire()` to capture all the allowed connections in competition with the children and only when all possible connections have been collected can the main continue. This involves changing its `_value` attribute to match the number of children, however, which is not safe.

Is there a correct and safe way to do what I am asking?